# Splitting a list in two at the last element, giving the last element and a rest-list

Tags: list, prolog

For example, given the list [1,2,3,4,5] I want to find the last element (5) and the remaining "rest list" i.e. [1,2,3,4].

I thought about reversing the list, splitting the first element, and then re-reversing the split list. But am unable to figure out how to write a predicate for this. If there are better or simpler solutions that would be ideal, I have not found anything through google searches.

Comment: Can you share your own attempt? How would you construct an *inductive definition* for this problem?

Comment: How would you do the opposite: creating a predicate that returns the first element, and the rest?

Comment: Prolog is all about relations among predicate arguments. Try to understand how the standard append/3 predicate works. It offers an easy solution to your question.

Comment: I agree with CapelliC: you should not think about *input* or *output*, but how the parameters correspond to each other. Prolog aims to make predicates *multidirectional* (so one should be able to generate a list where the last element is `5`, and the previous ones are `[1,2,3,4]`, so in "reverse").

Comment: You can also think recursively. What does the simplest case look like? `split_last([X], ?, ?).` Then write a recursive predicate that defines what the solution looks like assuming that base case: `split_last([H|T], Front, Last) :- ??, split_last(T, ?, Last).`

Answer (score 1):

In Prolog one aims - frequently with *inductive definitions* - to describe how parameters in a predicate "relate" to each other, not how to "transform" input into output. This means that a lot of predicates like `member/3` and `append/3` can be used in a *multidirectional* way.

> **Example 1**: We can define an [**`append/3`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3) in an inductive definition as:
>
> 1. if `X` is an empty list, then for `append(X, Y, Z)`, `Y` is the same as `Z`; and
> 2. if `X` is non-empty then we calculate the `append/3` for the list `X` without the first element, and `Y`, and we prepend that list `ZT` with the first element of `X`.
>
> We can then translate that into:
>
> ```
> append([], Y, Y).               %% (1)
> append([XH|XT], Y, [XH|ZT]) :-  %% (2)
>     append(XT, Y, ZT).
> ```

> **Example 2**: In a similar way, we can define a "filter". We might for example want to obtain all the elements that are larger than 3 in a list. We can define this inductively as:
>
> 1. the elements larger than three in an empty list, is the empty list;
> 2. the elements larger than three in a non-empty list where the first element is less than or equal to three, is the list of elements larger than three of the rest of the items of that list; and
> 3. the elements larger than three in a non-empty list where the first element is larger than three, is the list of elements larger than three of the rest of the list, prepended with the first element of the list.
>
> We can then translate that into:
>
> ```
> larger_three([], []).          %% (1)
> larger_three([H|T], F) :-      %% (2)
>     H =< 3,
>     larger_three(T, F).
> larger_three([H|T], [H|F]) :-  %% (3)
>     H > 3,
>     larger_three(T, F).
> ```

The above examples are quite typical for list processing, usually there is one (or a few) base cases that deal with an empty list, or a list with a fixed number of elements, and then there is one (or a few) recursive cases, that deal with non-empty lists, that are written inductively (in terms of the predicate).

Here your base case will *not* deal with an empty list, since for an empty list, there is no "last" element. The base case will deal with a list with *one* element.

The recursive case will therefore deal with a list that contains at least two elements, and should thus be defined in terms of the predicate itself.

We thus can write an inductive definition as:

1. the "init" and "last" of a list with one element is ....
2. the "init" and "last of a list with at least two elements can be defined as the init and last of the ..., and the we ...

The "skeleton" thus looks like:

```
initlast([X], ___, ___).
initlast([X1, X2|T], __, ___) :-
    ___,
    initlast(___, ___, ___),
    ___.
```

with `___` elements that need to be filled in. The `___`s in the body define *pre-processing* and *post-processing*, and might simply not exist.